# Are there Visual Studio -like tools for creating forms in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, gui, programming, ide

I want to create forms in Linux.

I create Windows forms, but for example if I was to use Linux to develop is there any software I could use to create a form like you would in Visual Studio?

Comment: Define "better". Under Windows not only you have WSL, you have multiple Windows IDEs including VS Code which features code completion using ChatGPT4 or something. There's nothing like that in Linux.

Comment: There's no need to edit, you'd better ask at news.ycombinator.com This question won't have answers, only opinions.

Comment: @gsmyth377 "Why is Linux better for programming than Windows/Mac?" (which is still the Subject) is *definitely* opinion.

Comment: @RonJohn  please remove your comments

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there's quite a few GUI/form-editor IDEs:

- QT Creator: Cross-Platform (as in: Win/Mac/Linux/Android/iOs/automotive…) targeting, very powerful. Builds upon Qt5 / Qt6 as Framework, supports C++, Javascript, Python …
- JetBrains: Very powerful IDE framework, I think it originally came from the Java World, now supports a lot of languages / interfaces. If you're interested in running the same code on Linux and Windows, JetBrains Rider is the .NET / Xamarin/ WPF method
- Smaller, but also popular in the .NET domain is monodevelop, which integrates GTK# design
- Several game engine editors, which in the end are also UI editors, but probably not what you're aiming for
- Same for Web UI editors